# setTranslationX not working after onResume/onPause in an android Listview

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` with `onTouchListener` in a `ListView`. On swipe on the `ImageView`, `setTranslationX()` seems to work fine after `onCreate()`. But it ceases to work after `onPause()`/`onResume()`. I am using `ViewHolder`s to hold the `View` References.

Any pointers please..

Code :

```
public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) { ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 … 
holder.imgView.setPhotoId(photoId); 
holder.imgView.setBackgroundColor(color); 
} 



public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) { ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
… 
holder.imgView.setPhotoId(photoId); 
holder.imgView.setBackgroundColor(color); 
holder.imgView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}
```

The touchListener seems to work fine when the activity is first created. Bur after pressing the back button, the view.setTranslationX(0) does not seem to work.

Comment: most likely because you've implemented the viewholder pattern wrong. Let me just use my magic ball ... no wait: Post your code!

Comment: public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
  {
   ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   …
   holder.imgView.setPhotoId(photoId);
   holder.imgView.setBackgroundColor(color);
  }

Comment: public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ...   View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
   ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.imgView.setOnTouchListener(listener);  
   convertView.setTag(holder);
   return convertView;
  }

Comment: edit your question and post the code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after making view not clickable (view.setClickable(false)). Thanks.

Comment: This wasn't the reason of your problem, Have you explored more into this?